# Multiple views in a JViewport?

Tags: java, swing

Currently I have a nifty JViewport with a Jlabel set up and used as a view. I'm wondering if it's possible to use layered Jlabels as the Viewport's view. IE: I want to add new JLabels into a pre-existing Viewport.

Thanks!

EDIT: On StanislavL's advice, I'm now using a JLayeredPane within an JScrollPane. Currently there are two JLabels in the JLayeredPane, when I scroll the JScrollPane, the larger background image scrolls properly, by the smaller shipSprite remains in the same position. Any ideas how I can get them to scroll together?

```
public void initViewport() {
    explorePort = new JScrollPane();
    explorePort.setBounds(0, 0, retailWidth, retailHeight);
    explorePort.setBackground(new Color(0, 100, 0));
    explorePort.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    explorePort.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    ImageIcon background = Main.global.imgScaler.scaleImage(new ImageIcon("images/blankgrid.jpg"), retailWidth*2, retailHeight*2);
    JLabel backSplash = new JLabel(background);
    backSplash.setBounds(0, 0, retailWidth*2, retailHeight*2);

    ImageIcon shipIcon = Main.global.imgScaler.scaleImage(new ImageIcon("images/ship.png"), Main.global.nodeWidth, Main.global.nodeHeight);
    JLabel shipSprite = new JLabel(shipIcon);
    shipSprite.setBounds(100, 100, Main.global.nodeWidth, Main.global.nodeHeight);

    Main.global.gamePanel.add(backSplash, 0);

    explorePort.setViewportView(backSplash);
    Main.global.gamePanel.add(shipSprite, 1);
    Main.global.gamePanel.add(explorePort, 2);

    //explorePort.addMouseListener(this);
    Main.global.gameFrame.addKeyListener(new ListenKey());
}
```

Comment: for better help sooner please edit your post with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), otherwise you have to accepted JLayeredPane or JLayer.... (@stas)+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Layered pane to add multiple lables to container and place the container in JScrollPane
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html